# How to insert a button in a dropdown selected option in Django?

Tags: html, django

I would like to insert a dropdown in Django that will return me to a page, and I am inserting a button that will lead to that page, but when I do this I return to the page I am currently in.

index.html

```
{% if lista_de_provas %}
  <form method='post' action=''>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <select class="form-control"  name="prova_selecionada" id="prova_selecionada">
    {% for prova in lista_de_provas %}
      <option id="{{prova.idProva}}" name="listaProvas" value='{{prova.idProva}}' disabled>{{prova.tipoProva}} {{prova.anoProva}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <input id="selProva" type="button" value="Confirma" onclick = "location.href ='{{prova.idProva}}';" />
  </form> 
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    lista_de_provas = Prova.objects.all()
    cprova = request.POST.get('idProva')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sprova = Prova.objects.get(cprova = cprova)
        sprova.select()
        return redirect('polls/detalhes.html')
    else:
        form = ProvaForm()
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html',{'form':form,'lista_de_provas': lista_de_provas})
```

Comment: When I put the button inside the for, 4 buttons appear and each one is directed to the right page that I desire. I would like only one button to appear.

Comment: So are you looking for only 1 button to appear in the dropdown? By the looks of it you are using `Prova.objects.all()` which must have 4 objects since you are looping through the whole object set.

Comment: Exactly. I did this just to test if it was working. Only works when you are inside the prova.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this.

First, you can specify explicitly what object you want. If you are looking for the second element you can do something like this:

```
{% if lista_de_provas %}
        <form method='post' action=''>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select class="form-control"  name="prova_selecionada" id="prova_selecionada">
            <option id="{{prova.1.idProva}}" name="listaProvas" value='{{prova.1.idProva}}' desabled>{{prova.1.tipoProva}} {{prova.1.anoProva}}</option>Mdjss.199
        </select>
        <input id="selProva" type="button" value="Confirma" onclick = "location.href ='{{prova.1.idProva}}';" />
        </form> 
      {% endif %}
```

Or to make it a bit more "Dynamic" and fail-safe, you can go in your view and use a `.filter()` on your object. So instead of `lista_de_provas = Prova.objects.all()` you can do something like:

```
lista_de_provas = Prova.objects.filter(id=2)
```

Sorry if I missed something. English is my first language.